# How to prove $a_0 + a_1 \cos \theta + a_2 \cos 2\theta + \cdots + a_n \cos n \theta$ has $2n$ different zeros, $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

$0 < a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_n$.
Prove that $a_0 + a_1 \cos \theta + a_2 \cos 2\theta + \cdots + a_n \cos n \theta$ has $2n$ different zeros, $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$.
[Hint: First prove that $P_n(z)=a_o+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n$ has $n$ zeros in unit ball $B(0,1)$.]

This is an assignment I copied from my textbook. It's in the section "The Argument Principle & Rouche Theorem".
Though I followed this hint, I still can't see how this would imply the desired conclusion. Help needed.

Comment: The complex function part is treated here :(https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188039). I discovered there that it is named "Eneström–Kakeya theorem"

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your help! But I still can't figure out how this result relates to my original problem concerning cos.

Comment: About the previous comment, yes, this hint refers to a special case of Eneström–Kakeya theorem, and you can prove it easily, but the expression $a_0 + a_1 \cos \theta + a_2 \cos 2\theta + \cdots + a_n \cos n \theta$ is vague for me. Is there something missing here?

Comment: @MyGlasses I directly copied this problem from my textbook.

Comment: Obviously this is the real part of $a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n$ when $|z=1|$. So can we relate the zeros of an holomorphic function on a bounded domain and the zeros of its real part on the boundary of the domain?

Comment: @Régis Yeah. But I can't see how this observation leads to the conclusion that the trigonometric polynomial has 2n different zeros.

Comment: Well if for instance it holds that $f$ has $n$ zeros on $\Omega$ implies $Re(f)$ has $2n$ zeros on $\partial \Omega$ we would be done. I don't know if this is true, but doesn't look quite unreasonable.

Answer (score 5):

#### Direct solution via intermediate value theorem

Multiply with the positive (on $(0,2\pi)$) factor $2\sin\fracθ2$ to get the equivalent equation
\begin{multline}
0=g(θ)=(a_0-a_1)\sin\tfrac12θ+(a_1-a_2)\sin\tfrac32θ+…\\…+(a_{n-1}-a_n)\sin((n-\tfrac12)θ)+a_n\sin((n+\tfrac12)θ)
\end{multline}
At the extremal points of $\sin((n+\tfrac12)θ)$, which are $$θ_k=\frac{2k+1}{2n+1}\pi, ~~~ k=0,1,...,2n,$$ the value $g(θ_k)$ has the same sign $(-1)^k$ as its last term. This is because it dominates the sum of the other terms, as $$a_n>a_n-a_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k-a_{k+1}|.$$ This is evidence for $2n$ sign alternations in the function value and thus at least $2n$ real roots inside the given interval $(0,2\pi)$.

#### Solution according to the hint

Per the hint, show that all the roots of $$p(z)=a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n$$ are inside the unit circle. As the elements of the coefficient sequence are separated by inequalities, one can modify the coefficients slightly without destroying this defining property. Then multiplying with a linear factor with a root at $1$ gives
$$
q(z)=(z-1)p(rz)=r^{n}a_nz^{n+1}+(r^{n-1}a_{n-1}-r^{n}a_n)z^n+...+(a_0-ra_1)z-a_0.
$$
The roots of $q(z)$ are contained in a circle of radius
$$
R=\max(1,r^{-n}|a_n|^{-1}(|r^{n-1}a_{n-1}-r^{n}a_n|+...+|a_0-ra_1|+|a_0|))=1.
$$
This bound is valid as long as $ra_{k+1}\ge a_k$, $k=0,..,n-1$. There is some $r<1$ that satisfies this finite number of inequalities.

So if $z$ is a root of $p$, then $z/r$ is a root of $q$, thus $|z/r|\le 1$, $|z|<r$. All roots of $p(z)$ are well inside the unit circle.

The path $p(e^{iθ})$, $θ\in[0,2\pi)$ of the image of one rotation along the unit circle has winding number $n$ around zero. Which means it crosses the positive real half axis at least $n$ times and also the negative real half-axis at least $n$ times. These crossing points are also roots for $f(θ)=Re(p(e^{iθ}))$, the function under consideration. Thus
$$
f(θ)=a_0 + a_1 \cos \theta + a_2 \cos 2\theta + \cdots + a_n \cos n \theta
$$
has at least $2n$ roots in $(0,2\pi)$. Note that $f(0)=a_n+...+a_1+a_0>0$.

Comment: So you didn't use the given hint?

Comment: No, but you can prove that hint via multiplication $q(z)=(z-1)p(z)=a_nz^{n+1}-(a_n-a_{n-1})z^n-…-(a_1-a_0)z-a_0$ which has an outer root radius of $1$ by the Lagrange bound.

Comment: Yeah I now know how to prove the hint. Still having difficulty relating the hint to the original problem.

Comment: The idea of the winding number might help, the image of the unit circle crosses the real axis twice per winding.

Comment: How does your second argument demonstrate simple zeros?

Comment: @BobbyOcean : t does not. That the winding number is $n$ means that there are at least $n$ crossings in positive orientation on each the positive and negative half-axis. The resulting $2n$ roots can have multiplicities greater than $1$, I'm not sure that one can control that with a simple argument.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misread, I thought the statement was to prove that the zeros were different from each other and I didn't see how your argument achieved that.

Comment: There are $n$ rotations around the origin. Each of them has a different segment of $[0,2\pi)$ as pre-image. Each segment contains 2 roots of the real part, one with positive and one with negative imaginary part. Thus $2n$ distinct roots.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not following, how you conclude "Thus 2n distinct roots". You don't know their distinct. They could have multiplicity higher than 1. I don't see how the winding number or argument theorem alone give you simple zeros. The OP question seems to indicate to show that there are "2n different zeros". Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $p$ maps the unit circle to a path that winds $n$ times around the origin, without crossing the origin. Despite all possible back-and-forth, in each circumnavigation of the origin the path has to cross each coordinate half-axis at least once in the order of a counter-clockwise rotations. Each such intersection is a root of the real or imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have provided does not appear to be a simple application of Rouche's theorem or equivalent. I would be curious what the author's thoughts were for a proof. In particular, I believe the problem is equivalent to the following non-trivial theorem.

**Theorem**. If $0<a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_n$ and $p(z)=a_0+\cdots+a_nz^n$, then $$q(z):=z^{-n}p(z^{-1})+z^np(z)$$ has only simple zeros located on the unit circle.

The equivalency can be easily verified. Indeed, if we define $$c(z):=a_0+a_1\cos(z)+a_2\cos(2z)+⋯+a_n\cos(nz)\ \ \ ,$$ then the statement "$c(z)$ has $2n$ simple zeros in the interval $(0,2\pi)$" is equivalent to the statement that "$q(z)$ has $2n$ simple zeros on the unit circle". This is because $\cos(z)=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$, hence $$c(z)=e^{-inz}/2*q(e^{iz})\ \ \ .$$ Thus $c(z)$ has a zero in $(0,2\pi)$ if and only if $q(z)$ has a zero on the unit circle.

I would gladly welcome a simple proof of the above theorem with an application of Rouche's theorem or similar, but this appears to not be the case. In fact, if you generalize $p(z)$ to polynomials with zeros in the unit disc and throw in a rotation coefficient of $|a|=1$, the above theorem is precisely the **complete** characterization of all polynomials with zeros on the unit circle, something that was only established in 1995. See the first answer here [To prove this complex polynomial has all zeros on unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867408/to-prove-this-complex-polynomial-has-all-zeros-on-unit-circle), Chen (J. of Math. Anal. and Appl. vol 190, 714-724 (1995)).